# MATLAB: Create a colored surface based on scatter points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface, colormap

Using a dataset of the format `[x,y,z,value]`, I can create a 3D scatter plot as shown in the images, where the color of each point at location `(x,y,z)` is based on `value`. Note that all of the images are of the same plot, just from different views. It is intended to be the surface of an octant of a sphere.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way I can do an interpolation of the colors in 3D such that we see a solid surface instead of individual points? I am looking for something along the lines of `imagesc`, but in 3D. I've tried a wide variety of functions, including `scatteredInterpolant`, `patch`, `mesh`, and `surf`, but those do not seem to work in 3 dimensions the way I'd like.

Comment: Why does `surf(x,y,z,c)` not work?

Comment: I get the error "Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector." I have no idea how I'd convert a position vector into a matrix

Comment: Can you post some example data?

Comment: I uplodaed the [full dataset](http://www.philipchow.info/uploads/dataset.txt). The first three columns are `[x,y,z]`; the remaining columns are different values. I'm reading in each column one at a time so that the `[x,y,z,value]` format still applies. You should use csvread to import data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example data (with multiple shells), I put this program together. It uses `trisurf` so it doesn't need meshed data.

```
function PlotColoredSpheres(x,y,z)
    tol = 0.01;

    r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2);
    data = num2cell(sortrows([r, x, y, z], [1,2,3,4]),1);
    [R, X, Y, Z] = data{:};

    figure(1)

    RUnique = uniquetol(r, tol);

    for Ru = RUnique(:)'
        j = abs(R - Ru) < tol;
        tri = delaunay(X(j),Y(j));
        trisurf(tri, X(j), Y(j), Z(j));
        lighting phong
        shading interp
        hold on
    end
    hold off
end
```